# Proving bijection $\phi:C(0,X)\to X,\ \phi(f):=f(0)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

For any space $X$, $$\phi:C(0,X)\to X,\ \phi(f):=f(0)$$
I am trying to show this is a bijection. I first show it is injective since if $\phi(f)=\phi(g)$, then $f(0)=g(0)$ which means $f=g$ since that represents the whole range.
However, I cannot show surjection. I was thinking for all $x\in X$, there is an $f$ s.t. $f(0)=x$ but that is not true because we know nothing about $f$.

Comment: What does $C(0,X)$ mean? If it stands for continuous functions from $\{0\}$ to $X$ then $f(0)=x$ defines your $f$ completely for any $x \in X$ proving surjectivity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes that is what $C(0,x)$ means. Could you please elaborate on how it proves surjectivity since I am still unsure? Could you also let me know if my reasoning for injectivity is correct? Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to prove that for any $x$ in the codomain, there is an $f$ such that $\phi(f)=f(0)=x$, but how do I know there is an $f$ that maps zero to $x$ for every $x\in X$?